# Can I somehow set the script interpreter in Apache, as opposed to the start of the file?

Tags: apache, lua, cgi

I am having the following problem:
When I want to run an uncompiled Lua script in Apache, I just add `#!/usr/share/lua` at the beginning of the file, so far everything works fine.

But if I want to compile it with `luac` to have it run a bit faster I cannot add any text to the file, as it is compiled binary data (which still needs to be interpreted by the Lua interpreter, and cannot be executed on its own).

Is there a way to tell Apache to always have `/usr/share/lua` interpret files with the `.lua` (or `.luac` to mark them as compiled) extension?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a way to do this as a CGI script, as the CGI spec basically requires that the shell can figure out how to run a file based on the hashbang at the beginning.

However, you could write a simple CGI handler in Lua that does a `loadfile()` on the `.luac` file and then executes it. You can set `.luac` files to be handled by this script with the following directives in a `.htaccess` or `httpd.conf` file:

```
# Files of a particular file extension
AddHandler my-file-type .xyz
Action my-file-type /cgi-bin/program.cgi
```

In this example [from the docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_actions.html#action), `program.cgi` would be passed the filename requested by the URL so you could parse it and run that file.